# "But" usage grammar

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, coordinating-conjunctions

I read the below sentence somewhere. I think it's not making sense. "But" is contradicting the earlier said clause.

"He is dead, this is what the police is concluding after searching for him across the entire city, but there’s no sign of him."

I guess it should be like--

"He is dead, this is what the police is concluding after searching for him across the entire city. There’s no sign of him."

Comment: I think that the writer is saying is that the police have been looking for the missing man, believe that he is dead, but cannot prove it as they have found no body. The sentence is clumsy and a bit unclear but saying that there is no sign of him does indicate that they cannot be completely certain that the man is dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is incorrectly formed. However, "There’s no sign of him." is not a separate sentence.

Apparently, the writer's intention seems to be:
"He is dead, this is what the police is concluding after searching for him across the entire city **and finding** no sign of him."